# Logo Magento Low res in retina

Tags: logo

I have [this](http://new.acquedilusso.it/) web site:

My costumer says the logo is `low resolution` in retina.

I am using `porto theme`.

How I can to create a low in high resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

you can add below css in the end of below css file
`http://new.acquedilusso.it/skin/frontend/acquedilusso/acquedilusso-child/css/local.css`

```
.header .logo img {
   max-width: inherit;
}
```